# Vis timeline fit in IE11

Tags: javascript, vis.js

My question is in relation to the fit() method of the vis Timeline. I am using the timeline on a webapp to be used in IE11. When I use fit() I am getting two results that I am unhappy with.

First is when add an item to timeline that isn't within the current visible timeline and then use fit(), the timeline fits the box/point at the very right hand side of the timeline and zooms the time in to milliseconds (this I can change with timaxis scale so will try this). How can I get the item in the center of the timline?

Secondly the fit will not work for items that are over a few weeks ahead or behind the visible region. I guess it just doesn't work at all really, whether the item is far ahead or behind it always appears on the very LHS of the visible region until I zoom out completely.

I was thinking of maybe getting the earliest start time in the 'items' dataset and the latest date and setting visible window to that range? Anyone have an idea how to achieve that? (I'm a relative newbie so I guess I could figure it our but I'm sure someone has had this issue before?)

My options are:

```
var options = {
    "showCurrentTime":true,
    "stack":false,
    "clickToUse":false,

    //"configure": true,
// option groupOrder can be a property name or a sort function
// the sort function must compare two groups and return a value
//     > 0 when a > b
//     < 0 when a < b
//       0 when a == b
  groupOrder: function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  },
  groupOrderSwap: function (a, b, groups) {
    var v = a.value;
    a.value = b.value;
    b.value = v;
  },
  editable: {
    add: false,         // add new items by double tapping
    updateTime: true,  // drag items horizontally
    updateGroup: false, // drag items from one group to another
    remove: true       // delete an item by tapping the delete button top right
  },
  groupEditable: false,
  onRemove: function (item){
    var ID = item.id;
    Titems.remove(ID);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Titems));
    timeline.setItems(Titems);
  }

};
```

Any ideas?